# How to reduce number of elements within Context Menu

Tags: eclipse

I just want to remove some of the elements from the menu below. The question is - how?

[image: context menu with too many elements]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide/remove arbitrary context menu items in Eclipse (3.6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482312/is-it-possible-to-hide-remove-arbitrary-context-menu-items-in-eclipse-3-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482312/is-it-possible-to-hide-remove-arbitrary-context-menu-items-in-eclipse-3-6). There is a guide there using the "Customize perspective" option in the menu which may work. A comment indicates that it doesnt, but its worth trying out.

But if you have a context menu that is too full, it may be a warning that you are using to many plugins in the same perspective. Unfortunately too often plugins have a tendency to add themselves a little all over the place.