# Eclipse RCP text editor - hiding context menu elements

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to implement a slightly customized XML editor for my Eclipse RCP application. The editor extends the TextEditor class and works just fine. Except that it puts a lot of stuff to the context (right-click) popup menu I don't really need. I found that I need to overwrite the **editorContextMenuAboutToShow** function:

```
@Override
public void editorContextMenuAboutToShow(IMenuManager menu) {
    menu.removeAll();
}
```

This works fine except that I still have menus in my context menu, namely **Debug As, Run As, Validate, Team, Compare** etc. menus and their submenus.

I'm not sure what else to do and this is very annoying since I do not want the user to get access to these features. I'd appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: The extra items are because `AbstractTextEditor` calls `IEditorSite.registerContextMenu` to register the context menu which lets other plug-ins add to the menu. I can't see an obvious way to stop this.

Comment: Thank you Greg for the help! It seems we need to implement our own AbstractTextEditor then if we wantto overwrite these.

Comment: Is that on Eclipse 3.x? Then this post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482312/is-it-possible-to-hide-remove-arbitrary-context-menu-items-in-eclipse-3-6

Comment: You may be able to use the `activityPatternBinding` mentioned in the question referenced in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess **activities** don't work with `Context` Menus.

I was able to remove all context menus , but except "Github"-menu by adding following single line code to `editorContextMenuAboutToShow()` method :

```
ObjectActionContributorManager.getManager().unregisterAllContributors();
```