# Remove Eclipse menu option

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services

I want to remove an Eclipse menu option (Amazon Web Services)

[image]

Comment: What for? Leave it there, it's not like it is hurting anyone. There is a possible solution in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482312/is-it-possible-to-hide-remove-arbitrary-context-menu-items-in-eclipse-3-6) btw

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the AWS features completely from your Eclipse installation, or just not see the menu item?

Comment: just not see the menu item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to really remove the AWS features you need to uninstall the AWS plug-in(s) that contribute it. In the Help menu, select **Installation Details**. In the resulting dialog you can find the Amazon Web Services feature(s), select it, then use the **Uninstall...** button to uninstall it.

On the other hand, if you just want to hide the menu item but leave the AWS features in Eclipse, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3482357/639520